# How i could add prefix in smooks config WSO2?

Tags: wso2

I need to transform my csv file to XML with elements with prefixes "api".
I have WSO2 ESB configuration like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <proxy name="c"
          transports="https http local vfs"
          startOnLoad="true"
          trace="enable">
      <description/>
      <target>
         <inSequence>
            <smooks config-key="sm">
               <input type="text"/>
               <output type="xml"/>
            </smooks>
            <log level="full"/>
         </inSequence>
         <outSequence/>
         <faultSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
         </faultSequence>
      </target>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file://D:\test\out</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file://D:\test</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file://D:\test\fail</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.csv</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   </proxy>
   <localEntry key="sm">
      <smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
                            xmlns:core="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/smooks-core-1.3.xsd"
                            xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.2.xsd">
         <resource-config selector="org.xml.sax.driver">
            <resource>org.milyn.csv.CSVReader</resource>
            <param name="fields">code,name</param>
            <param name="rootElementName">api:root</param>
            <param name="recordElementName">api:rec</param>
         </resource-config>
      </smooks-resource-list>
   </localEntry>
   <sequence name="fault">
      <log level="full">
         <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default &#34;fault&#34; sequence"/>
         <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
         <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
      </log>
      <drop/>
   </sequence>
   <sequence name="main">
      <log/>
      <drop/>
   </sequence>
</definitions>
```

Without prefix api it works, else - not. 
Where I just did not added namespaces - it's did not help me.
Anybody can help? Thanks.